# How to get object-level Validation errors with django-rest-framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

We are using django-rest-framework for a form with a list of objects. All of these have values and have to be validated on an object-level.

**This is the POST, sending a list of 3 Steps**

```
"steps":[  
   {  
      "start_date":"2016-03-19",
      ...
   },
   {  
      "start_date":"2018-06-19",
      ...

   },
   {  
      "start_date":"2018-06-19",
      ...
   }
]
```

**Answer with an unspecific Validation Error**

```
{  
   "steps":[  
      {  
         "start_date":[  
            "The start date must be in the future." // Which one? Step 1, 2 or 3?
         ]
      },

   ]
}
```

**Serializer:**

```
class StepSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    position = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    // start_date comes from the Model

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = ...
    steps = StepSerializer()
```

**View:**

```
class ProjectViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
```

**Question:** How can the answer contain an info about the object, which had an error?

Thanks for any help on this!

Best regards
Jens

Comment: Is it possible to see the `serializer` and `view` code for the end point that receives the POST request?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I added the `serializer` and `view` as an example.